# No constructive feedback and blocked

Tags: support, status-completed

I asked and now I'm temporarily blocked. There is not a single constructive feedback anywhere. If you block a user, you should let the user know what he did wrong.

This is what is says

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
>   break - take a breather and come back soon!

Comment: You have [a deleted question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20558/can-you-please-help-me-translate) that has received downvotes (-3 score). It must be an automatic suspension to enforce you read the site rules and scope.

Comment: Yes, it has to be an automatic block, because your rep is 106, so it can't be a manual ban. I'm surprised just one bad question triggered it. Usually takes more than that. What is the error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were question-banned. However, unlike suspensions, post bans are **automatic and done by the site**.

As explained in [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> ### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways**.
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> **Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions [you can see a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.
>
> If you really, *really* think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

Therefore:

- Undelete your question and fix it if possible.
- Post high-quality answers until you make enough positive contributions so that the ban is lifted.

Comment: The OP edited his question; he's not getting "we are no longer accepting...", he is getting "looks like you've reached your limit". Which makes more sense anyway; I've never heard of one bad question triggering the question ban. Most likely he's on a shared IP and other people using it in total trigger the "too many questions too quickly" rule:

Comment: @DanBron Uhm no it's not that. Besides, how the question ban works is quite vague on purpose. We can't really tell if it's weird or not.